# How to change a portion of text on hover with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my website to show: `(855) TRY PETS` when the user isn't hovered over the text but I want the text to show: `(855) 879 7387` when the user does hover over the text.

Currently I have:

```html
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-phone-sign"></i>(855) TRY PETS</a></li>
```

Is there an easy way to make this change with css?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS only method:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zu6E4/)

HTML and CSS:

```css
li a:before {
  content:"(855) TRY PETS"
}

li a:hover:before {
  content:"(855) 879 7387"
}
```

```html
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
```

Comment: Your solution is way better. I`ll delete mine.